# What is the difference between data class and class (Python)?

Tags: python, object, oop, python-dataclasses

Is there any difference except the writing `__init__` method between data class and class (Python)?

Comment: `class` is a general mechanism for defining your own classes. `@dataclass` is a decorator that you use with your classes to automatically define some standard methods.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html for the full list of what `@dataclass` does.